# understanding Docker compose mongodb and rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

there is ruby on rails application which uses mongodb and postgresql databases. When I run it locally everything works fine, however when I try to open in a remote container, it throws error message

`2021-03-14T20:22:27.985+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers`

the docker-compose.yml file defines following services:

`redis  mongodb  db rails`

I start remote containers with following command:

`docker-compose build` - build successful

`docker-compose up -d` - containers are up and running

when I connect to the `rails` container and try to do

`bundle exec rake aws:restore_db`

error mentioned above is thrown. I don't know what is wrong here. The `mongodb` container is up and running.

the docker-compose.yml is mentioned below:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.5
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6.13
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  db:
    image: postgres:11.3
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  rails:
    build: .
    image: proj:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
      - mongodb
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/proj
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    env_file:
      - .env/development.env
volumes:
  db-data:
  mongo-data:
```

this is how I start all four remote containers:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Starting proj_db_1      ... done
Starting proj_redis_1   ... done
Starting proj_mongodb_1 ... done
Starting proj_rails_1   ... done
```

please help me to understand how remote containers should interact with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration should point to the services by name and not to a port on localhost. For example, if you ware connecting to `redis` as `localhost:6380` or `127.0.0.1:6380`, now you need to use `redis:6380`

If this is still not helping, you can try to add links between containers in order the names given to them as services to be resolved. So the file will look something like this:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.5
    networks:
      - front-end
    links:
      - "mongodb:mongodb"
      - "db:db"
      - "rails:rails"
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6.13
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - front-end
    links:
      - "redis:redis"
      - "db:db"
      - "rails:rails"
  db:
    image: postgres:11.3
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - front-end
    links:
      - "redis:redis"
      - "mongodb:mongodb"
      - "rails:rails"
  rails:
    build: .
    image: proj:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
      - mongodb
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/proj
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    env_file:
      - .env/development.env
    networks:
      - front-end
    links:
      - "redis:redis"
      - "mongodb:mongodb"
      - "db:db"
volumes:
  db-data:
  mongo-data:

networks:
  front-end:
```

The links will allow for a hostnames to be defined in the containers.

> The `link` flag is legacy, and in new versions of docker-engine it's not required for user defined networks. Also, the links will be ignored in case of docker swarm deployment. However since there are sill old installations of Docker and docker-compose, this is one thing to try in troubleshooting.

Comment: adding network and links doesn't solve the problem. After adding links and network I still have that error

Comment: 1) what is your conneciton string, 2) from which container are you trying to connect to which container (ex. rails to redis)

Comment: I connect to the rails container to run the bash script `docker-compose exec rails bash` and then do `bundle exec rake aws:restore_db` . The connection string seems to be correct, the mongoid.yml contains hosts set to mongodb:27017

Comment: can you do `cat /etc/hosts` from `rails` container and check that the `mongodb` is listed inside.

Comment: the problem was connection string pointing to localhost instead of mongodb. everything works fine. cheers!